# Emulating MySQL Workbench "standard TCP/IP over SSH" from the command line

Tags: mysql, ssh, port, mysql-workbench

MySQL workbench has a handy connection option - 'standard TCP/IP over SSH'. This allows me to connect to a publicly-inaccessible MySQL server (let's call it `mysql@private.com`), by SSH-ing onto a remote server (let's call it `myserver@public.com`) that is on the same network as the MySQL server.

I am trying to re-create this using the MySQL command line client and persistently failing. I have tried opening an SSH tunnel to forward port 3306 from `myserver@public.com`, to `127.0.0.1` (ie, `localhost`). This does not work, because at no point have I specified where to find `mysql@private.com`.

I presume MySQL workbench must pull off this handy trick via some combination of the MySQL client CLI and generally-availble tools like SSH. If anyone could show me how it's done, I'd be most grateful.

Comment: SSH tunneling works this way: you could set (in your SSH connection) a port on SSH host that will be automatically redirected to some host/port, then you can use SSH host/port to go to private host/port.
So while establishing connection you could set port 33306 to go to mysql@private.com:3306; then you can connect to localhost:33306 and you're done

Comment: @Marco - thanks - so if I understand you correctly: 
1. `ssh -L 33306:127.0.0.1:33306 myserver@public.com`; 
2. then whilst ssh-ed in: `ssh -L 3306:127.0.0.1:33306 mysql@private.com`
3. then from my local machine, `mysql localhost:33306`?

Comment: If you use putty to create SSH connection (on your PC!) you can create a new connection directed to `myserver@public.com`; in this connection you set a forwarding port, eg 33306 to `mysql@private.com:3306`. When you establish connection, your local port 33306 will be automatically redirected to the private server through the public one, as long as putty connection in active! So you have to do absolutely nothing on public server but having an active SSH server.

Answer (score 0):

As is customary with SO I googled for about three hours before posting this question then found the answer within about three minutes of posting it. There is a detailed guide here:
https://medium.com/@deepspaceprog/how-to-connect-via-ssh-to-an-amazon-rds-instance-running-postgresql-5e7661cdd37e
That says it better than I can but the critical command is this:

`ssh -N -L 3306:mysql@private.com:3306 myserver@public.com`

If I paraphrase this into English, I believe it might say
"ssh into myserver@public.com; forward port 3306 on the local connection mysql@private.com to 3306 on the local machine".

Comment: Better: ssh into myserver@public.com and forward local port 3306 (local on pc where you're running ssh command) to port 3306 on mysql@private.com (that must be known by myserver@public.com)

Comment: @Marco - why is that better?

Comment: I think it's a better explanation of what happens...